# AWS Lambda - cannot find module

Tags: aws-lambda

My zip file contains: mylambda.js node_modules

mylambda requires mycommon.

Inside the node_modules there is a module called "mycommon".

Inside node_modules/mycommon there is a "node_modules" with "bunyan" inside there.  (It is a dependency of mycommon module.)

It is being required from node_modules/mycommon/src/logging.js.

No matter what I do, even if I put bunyan in the top level node_modules, I always get the error "Cannot find module "bunyan"" from node_modules/mycommon/src/logging.js.

What is the recommended way to deal with this? Is there a lambda bundler that can take care of this for me? (Like browserify.)

Thanks much.

Comment: Why is "bunyan" not listed as a dependency for "mycommon"? You shouldn't have to manually add the dependencies for libs in your node_modules.